# Java [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (near "resi": syntax error)

Tags: java, sqlite

i have some issues when i'm run the program. It says "[SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (near "resi": syntax error)" and "ada yang salah:java.sql.SQLException: ResultSet is TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY". Am i passed something or what?

connection code

```
public void koneksiDatabase(){
    try{
        Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
        con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:C:/Users/sqlite3/cekresi.db","root","");
        System.out.println("Koneksi berhasil!");
    }catch(ClassNotFoundException eclass){
        System.out.println("Koneksi Gagal!");
    }catch(SQLException esql){
        System.out.println(esql.getMessage());
    }
}
```

savedata code

```
public void simpanData(){
    try {
        String sql = "Insert into data resi = \"" + txtResi.getText() + "\","
                + "nama = \"" + txtNama.getText() + "\","
                + "tujuan = \"" + (String)cmbTujuan.getSelectedItem() + "\","
                + "tarif = \"" + txtTarif.getText() + "\","
                + "berat = \"" + txtBerat.getText() + "\","
                + "jumlah = \"" + txtJumlah.getText() + "\"";
        Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
        stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
        System.out.println("berhasil!");
    }catch (Exception e){
        System.out.println(e);
    }
    tampilDataKeTabel();
}
```

showtable code

```
public void tampilDataKeTabel(){
    ResultSet rs = null;
    try{
        Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
        rs = stmt.executeQuery("select * from data");
        
        ResultSetMetaData meta = rs.getMetaData();
        int col = meta.getColumnCount();
        int baris = 0;
        while (rs.next()){
            baris = rs.getRow();
        }
        dataTable = new String[baris][col];
        int x = 0;
        rs.beforeFirst();
        while(rs.next()){
            dataTable[x][0] = rs.getString("resi");
            dataTable[x][1] = rs.getString("nama");
            dataTable[x][2] = rs.getString("tujuan");
            dataTable[x][3] = rs.getString("tarif");
            dataTable[x][4] = rs.getString("berat");
            dataTable[x][5] = rs.getString("jumlah");
            x++;
        }
        tabelDisplay.setModel(new DefaultTableModel(dataTable,header));
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.err.println("ada yang salah:"+e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your insert syntax looks way off. Are you sure your database supports that?

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: Have you tried executing the insert command in the `sql-lite` command line? The `insert` statement looks to be incorrect

Answer (score 0):

There are syntax issues in the insert statement. The syntax should be:

```
INSERT INTO table (column1,column2 ,..)
VALUES( value1, value2 ,...);
```

So your insert statement should be something like:

```
String sql = "Insert into data(resi,nama,tujuan,tarif,berat,jumlah)
              values(\"" + txtResi.getText() + "\","
                + \"" + txtNama.getText() + "\","
                + \"" + (String)cmbTujuan.getSelectedItem() + "\","
                + \"" + txtTarif.getText() + "\","
                + \"" + txtBerat.getText() + "\","
                + \"" + txtJumlah.getText() + "\")";
```

Also, there is an issue in the code to show the data.

```
while (rs.next()){
    baris = rs.getRow();
}
```

This loop is traversing the result set once. So the next loop would fail as rs has already reached the end of results.

This is causing the exception : `ResultSet is TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY`

Instead of creating a 2D string array, Create a class corresponding to your db table and then create a `List`. Assuming a class named `Data` would be created, the second while loop would be :

```
List<Data> dataList = new ArrayList<>();
while(rs.next()){
    Data data = new Data();
    data.setResi(rs.getString("resi"));
    data.setNama(rs.getString("nama"));
    data.setTujuan(rs.getString("tujuan"));
    data.setTarif(rs.getString("tarif"));
    data.setBerat(rs.getString("berat"));
    data.setJumlah(rs.getString("jumlah"));
    dataList.add(data);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, sir. That's helped me. But, it says that "Cannot find symbol - class list", would you help me once more? I'm very new to Java Language.

Comment: have you imported `java.util.List` ?